# Error Email From Amazon MySQL RDS instance "awsrds-***-production-High-DB-Connections"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have MySQL Amazon RDS production instance, we have activated email for error in Amazon. We have got the following email where our MySQL server instance is stopped and get restarted automatically. I want to to know the reason for this.

The error email message is:

```
reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (201.0) was greater than or equal to the threshold (200.0).

- Timestamp:                  Sunda
- AWS Account:                 Threshold:

- The alarm is in the ALARM state when the metric is GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold 200.0 for 60 seconds. 
Monitored Metric:
- MetricNamespace:            AWS/RDS
- MetricName:                 DatabaseConnections " It seems high DB connection reaches in MySQL server.
```

We are unable to find the exact reason for this.

Answer (score 2):

Your amazon RDS instance is configured to have a maximum of 200 connections. You simply had 201 connections, and amazon let you know about it. You can read more about [cloudwatch alarms here in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch).

As for solutions, you should ensure your code is closing database connections properly, and if its really experiencing that many simultaneous connections, upgrade your database to an instance that can handle it.

Comment: Hi jpschroeder, Thank you for valuable comments. Please give me the idea to change the number of connections in amazon instance. I have no idea. However i checked in MySQL instance by querying the "max_connections", It showed me the allowed number of connection for the MySQL instance is "1412". I do not have any idea about the threshold level for number of connections. Please suggest me on this. Which parameter i need to change in amazon RDS MySQL instance?